# Clever git add command

Tags: git, glob

Imagine that we have edited file foo.c.

It is possible to write `git add foo*`, but what if I want to write `git add *o*` to reduce keystrokes? Is there any way to get this behavior in git CLI interface?

Comment: Have you looked at git add -u to add all updated files? you can also look into git add -p for adding patch sets.

Comment: If you're concerned about key strokes what's wrong with tab to autocomplete? If autocomplete can't determine what it is, you're not going to develop a more efficient regex in less characters

Answer (score 2):

Is is already possible, if you work in a **POSIX-compliant shell** (like Bash).  Indeed, it is the shell itself and not the `git` client that expands `foo*` or `*o*` to `foo.c`.

But **be aware** that, should you happen to have another file matching the globbing pattern (e.g. `not-to-be-added.c`), it would be added as well.

Comment: I had to specify my question: is it possible to add tab-completion support when I type *o<tab>? At the moment I am using default git-completion script from git

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for actually works.

```
$ touch foo.c
$ touch bar.c

$ git status
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   bar.c
#   foo.c

$ git add *o*

$ git status
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   foo.c
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   bar.c
```

Comment: I had to specify my question: is it possible to add tab-completion support when I type *o<tab>? At the moment I am using default git-completion script from git